# Mac Printing : programatically can not set printQuality, mediaType, paperSource, outputBin

Tags: macos, api, printing

I have a Mac application that supports customising field values programatically for Print dialog. However, I could not find any API in Mac (Cocoa/Carbon) to set the values for:

- printQuality (Best/Normal/Low/Draft),
- mediaType(Standard/Glossy/Transparent),
- paperSource or PaperFeed(Auto/Manual/Casette/Env) and
- outputBin(Auto/Bin1/Bin2).

Though I find constants for these fields as:

```
PMQuality, PMPaperType, PMPaperSource, PMPSTraySwitch
```

I am not successful in using them to set the values to printer. I couldn't find which object/dictionary/array can contain these keys to be effective.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Basically u mihgt have to redraw another pdf. have a look at this code. this should help
http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/grDevices/src/qdCocoa.m

Comment: i haave to print a 300 dpi image. But in current situation it looks like printing at 72 dpi. So what i have to do ?

Comment: NOT SURE. never came across this .. have a look at this
http://pdfpack.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/MyContentView.rb